# TypeError: restify.authorizationParser is not a function in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, restify

I am facing this error and have tried multiple version of restify like **4.1.1**,  **6.0.0 , ^4.3.2**.

But its working fine on my local machine but not working on the production.

> ***TypeError:  restify.authorizationParser is not a function***

Please, could you help me. I'll be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be part of the plugins module in latest.

The following should get rid of that error:

```
server.use(restify.plugins.authorizationParser());
```

Answer (score 1):

please update node version and pick up the restify version **6.0.0**.